# Change text of "Save" button to "Send" in share point Form

Tags: office-365, form

I want to change text of **Save** button to **Send** button in SharePoint Online

Comment: Can you please add some more details. Like the purpose of it. Or is it just the text you want to replace or entire functionality.

Comment: i used sp list to send thank you mail. so i need to change save botton in my form to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is little bit tricky task.
You can use Content Editor WebPart for this and do some tricks.

For more detail please see [SharePoint change Save button to Send](https://sharepointonline.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/sharepoint-change-save-button-to-send/)

Another Approach for you may be :

- Create a JavaScript file and keep the code from above link.
- Upload it into Document Library and get the link
- Edit the page and WebPart where you want to change
- Locate `JSLink` under `Miscellaneous` group.
- Give the link of the JS file which you just uploaded

And your task is done without using CEWP.

Let me know whether it solved your problem. It is working at my end.

Thanks

Comment: thanks aakash. but its a support project i dont hav rights CEWP. can u give another solution ?

Comment: Updated one more approach in answer

Comment: ill workout here and inform , thanks u so much for your support mr aakash.